# FeathersJS cannot create user with ObjectionJS and SQLite

Tags: node.js, sqlite, knex.js, feathersjs, objection.js

I am experimenting with FeathersJS. To do so, I generated a new feathers app
`$ feathers g app` with the following configuration:

```
? Do you want to use JavaScript or TypeScript? JavaScript
? Project name test
? Description
? What folder should the source files live in? src
? Which package manager are you using (has to be installed globally)? npm
? What type of API are you making? REST, Realtime via Socket.io
? Which testing framework do you prefer? Mocha + assert
? This app uses authentication Yes
? Which coding style do you want to use? ESLint
? What authentication strategies do you want to use? (See API docs for all 180+ supported oAuth providers) Username + Password (Local)
? What is the name of the user (entity) service? users
? What kind of service is it? Objection
? Which database are you connecting to? SQLite
? What is the database connection string? sqlite://test.sqlite
```

When I run the test suite `$ npm run tests`, it throws an error `ERR GeneralError: strict mode: unknown keyword: "0"`

So far, I understood that this error is raised somewhere in AJV that is used by Knex and that it is somehow related to schema validation. I also tried posting to `http://localhost:3030/users` in order to create a users but I get the same error.

I ran the same experiment with apps configured to use Knex + SQLite and Sequalize + SQLite. Those setups let me create new users.

Does anyone have any idea where this error may come from and how to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the problem. The feathers generator creates the following jsonSchema within the ObjectionJS model:

```
 static get jsonSchema() {
    return {
      type: 'object',
      required: ['password'],

      properties: {
      
        email: { type: ['string', 'null'] },
        password: 'string',
      
      }
    };
  }
```

which features a wrong syntax for the password property. It needs to be `password: { type: 'string' }` to work.